# Box around icon in Boostrap alert

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

As the title says, there is a weird box around the icon in the alert. It looks like this.

[image]

But, it's fine everywhere else.

[image]

This is the file where code for the alert is.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h1>{% block page_title %}Page title{% endblock %}</h1>
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
        {% if messages %}
          {% for category, message in messages %}
            {% set alert_type = "success" %}
            {% if category == "error" %}
              {% set alert_type = "danger" %}
            {% endif %}

            <div class="alert alert-{{ alert_type }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
              {{ message }}
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
    </div>
    <p>{% block content %}Stuff here ...{% endblock %}</p>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is styling regarding the alert

```html
            <div class="alert alert-{{ alert_type }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
              {{ message }}
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
```

I copied the class names, the attributes from this [page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/) directly. Hard coding `alert-{{ alert_type }}` doesn't fix this issue. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are border styles being applied to the button in the browser in the absence of custom css. You can override and fix the issue.

This works to remove it:

```
  button.close{
  border: none !important;
background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

It might be best to get rid of span all together.

```
<div class=" alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">Holy guacamole!</strong>
<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/

Comment: Why wouldn't there be CSS? I used the CDN, which includes bootsrap CSS doesn't it? Also, I did get rid of the span and used the example you gave. The button looks fine, but, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did, but, the close button works now.

Comment: Glad you got it working. You did include the Bootstrap CSS and in order for those styles to take affect you would need to use a Bootstrap class such as this: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>

Comment: I see, so I wrote the name of the class wrongly then.